# It seems like the kubelet isn't running or healthy

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, virtual-kubelet

What did I want to do here?

I want to make 3 node Kubernetes cluster
First I install Ubuntu server 20.04.3 LTS in my VMware and this way too I make 3 servers.
After I install docker and Kubernetes and Kubernetes dependencies
and install kubeadmn with all dependencies. when I try to make the first master node with kubeadmn command  `kubeadm init`

after I face `kubelete isn't running or healthy` this error.

Then I follow a few solutions in stack overflow

```
 sudo systemctl daemon-reload
 sudo systemctl restart docker
 sudo systemctl restart kubelet
 kubeadm reset
 systemctl restart kubelet
 kubeadm init
```

still, I haven't solution found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution I found in stack overflow
[link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52119985/kubeadm-init-shows-kubelet-isnt-running-or-healthy)

what I did here

please create `vi /etc/docker/daemon.json`
and inside added below:

```
{ 
    "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"]
}
```

after run this command and solve the problem

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```